# Why are low-resolution versions of my images shown in Adobe Bridge?

Tags: software, resolution, adobe-camera-raw, adobe-bridge

When I browse photos in Adobe Bridge, they are often not as sharp as they really are, as if Bridge loads a low-res version of the photo for speed. This makes it hard to pick photos that are good, as I need to open them in Camera Raw to see how sharp they are first. The same low-res image is shown in Camera Raw the first seconds, until the image is "loaded fully" (I suppose).

Can I make Bridge show the high-res image?

Comment: eek this is annoying - I have the same problem - have you checked this post out http://forums.adobe.com/thread/561800?tstart=0

Comment: It appears your version of Adobe Bridge does not recognize the RAW files you use and uses the embedded JPEG. If you are not at the latest version, upgrade.

Comment: @Itai I was using 4.0.4, and yes there is a 4.0.5. But the change log only said something about Facebook.

Comment: @Rob Awesome thanks, that seems to have solved it for me :) If you add that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eek this is annoying - I have the same problem - have you checked this post out forums.adobe.com/thread/561800?tstart=0

Hope this works!

Rob